# merging columns from different files

Tags: linux, shell

i need an output file containing 62 columns, the first and second column from file1 and the rest of columns from the column 7 of another files... i did so
[izadi@lbox161 subread-1.4.6-p5-source]$ paste  <(cut -f1,7 counts018347.txt) <(cut -f7 counts019035.txt) <(cut -f7 SRR074122.txt) <(cut -f7 SRR074123.txt) <(cut -f7 SRR314813.txt) <(cut -f7 SRR314814.txt) <(cut -f7 SRR314815.txt) <(cut -f7 SRR314819.txt) <(cut -f7 SRR331224.txt) <(cut -f7 SRR346552.txt) <(cut -f7 SRR346553.txt) <(cut -f7 SRR390313.txt) <(cutcd /usr/data/nfs6/izadi/microarray/subread-1.4.6-p5-source/ad-1.4.6-p5-source]$ paste  <(cut -f1,7 counts018347.txt) <(cut -f7 counts019035.txt) <(cut -f7 SRR074122.txt)  > summary.txt
Too many ('s.
[izadi@lbox161 subread-1.4.6-p5-source]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use temporary files, like this:

```
cut -f1,7 counts018347.txt > tmp1
cut -f7 counts019035.txt   > tmp2
cut -f7 SRR074122.txt      > tmp3
cut ...
paste tmp1 tmp2 tmp3 tmp...> summary.txt
```